# Class that is privately inherited from std::runtime_error is not caught as std::exception

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

It's all in this example

```
class MyException: std::runtime_error // note, there is no public keyword in inheritance
{
public:
   MyException(const std::string & x)
      : std::runtime_error(x)
   {}
};


int main( )
{
   try
   {
      throw MyException("foo");
   }
   catch (std::exception & e )
   {
      std::cout << "catched std exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
   catch (...)
   {
      std::cout << "catched ... " << std::endl;
   }
}
```

It writes on stdout string "*catched ...*". But, if I change inheritance to public as `class MyException : public std::runtime_error`, it works as expected (for me) and writes "*catched std exception: foo*"

What part of the c++ standard requires such behavior? And why? In what cases such behavior could be useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense and is consistent with the rules for overload resolution. Outside of `MyException`, your class *is-not-an* `std::exception`. You should see private inheritance as an implementation detail (with very high coupling.)

It is in **15.3 Handling an exception**:

> A handler is a match for an exception object of type E if
>
> — The handler is of type cv T or cv T& and E and T are the same type
>   (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), or
>
> — the handler is of type cv
>   T or cv T& and T is an ***unambiguous public base class of E***, or
>
> — the handler is of type cv1 T* cv2 and E is a pointer type that can be
>   converted to the type of the handler by either or both of - a standard
>   pointer conversion (4.10) not involving conversions to pointers to
>   private or protected or ambiguous classes
>    — a qualification conversion
>
> — the handler is a pointer or pointer to member type and E is std::nullptr_t.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3):

Because *private inheritance* doesn't allow you to treat `Derived*/Derived&` as `Base*/Base&`. That means you cannot put `Derived*` where `Base*` is expected.

Actually private inheritance is used when you just want implementation of some class without accepting it's interface...

Answer (score 2):

It's private inheritance, `MyException` is not convertible to `std::runtime_error`.